# Twitter Bootstrap modal rails delete button not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am switching to Twitter Bootstrap 2.1.1.

I have a modal with a button to delete but it does not work. In previous bootstrap version it worked OK. Rails version is 3.1

Here is the code

```
<a title="<%= t('delete') %>" id="delete" class="label" href="#myModal-<%= post.id %>" data-toggle="modal"><%= t('delete') %></a>
```

the modal

```
<div class="modal hide" id="myModal-<%= post.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel"><%= t('delete_this_question') %></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p><%= raw post.text %></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><%= t('cancel') %></button>
        <%= link_to(t('delete'), { :controller => 'posts', :action => 'destroy', :id => post.id } ,:method => :delete, :class => 'btn btn-primary') %>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it does not work. Rails receives a GET and shows the post, but it does not destroy it.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: try post_path(post) and check

Comment: Thank you for your response @Amar.
I tried this 
<%= link_to(t('delete'), post_path(post), :class => 'btn btn-primary') %>
but does not work

Comment: check the necessary javascripts(belong to bootstrap framework) in your generated html.

Comment: I have bootstrap.min.js and it is supposed that contains all plugins for bootstrap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the following solution on http://rors.org/demos/custom-confirm-in-rails

You can use this completely unobtrusively without having to have a custom delete link or modal content in your view. So in my view I have the standard Rails link (only adding some classes to use the Bootstrap styles):

```
link_to 'delete', post, method: :delete, confirm: 'Are you sure?', class: 'btn btn-mini btn-danger'
```

And the following in /app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-confirmation.js.coffee

```
$.rails.allowAction = (link) ->
  return true unless link.attr('data-confirm')
  $.rails.showConfirmDialog(link) # look bellow for implementations
  false # always stops the action since code runs asynchronously

$.rails.confirmed = (link) ->
  link.removeAttr('data-confirm')
  link.trigger('click.rails')

$.rails.showConfirmDialog = (link) ->
  message = link.attr 'data-confirm'
  html = """
         <div class="modal" id="confirmationDialog">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
             <h3>Request confirmation</h3>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
             <p>#{message}</p>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
             <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</a>
             <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger confirm">Confirm</a>
           </div>
         </div>
         """
  $(html).modal()
  $('#confirmationDialog .confirm').on 'click', -> $.rails.confirmed(link)
```

If you want more post specific details in your modal you can always include them as data- attributes in your delete link (just like `data-confirm` is used to display the confirmation message.)

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I looked at your code and it seems ok to me. I don't see any reason why you should get a GET instead of a POST request. Did you have the same problem with my example? Still getting a GET request?

Comment: Yes, same code but I have bootstrap.min.js so I pasted your js code in a new file bootstrap-confirmation.js.coffee

Comment: That's correct, you need both. Hmm, very strange, you really should be getting DELETE not GET requests coming in (I said POST before but meant DELETE of course.) Hard to say what's going wrong. Your original link was missing some of the needed attributes, but if you use my example, the standard Rails link_to method, it should work. Can you show us the generated html from that link? It should look something like this: `<a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" href="/my_model/123">Delete</a>`

Comment: Thank you Peter. I copied and pasted your code and it does not work for me.

Generated code for link is:

<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" href="/en/posts/5026">delete</a>

Response from server is GET and modal is not shown

Comment: Hmm then there is something wrong with your javascript initialization. Three possibilities as far as I can determine, either the rails javascript integration isn't working (check if you have `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs` in your application.js) or the Twitter bootstrap modal script isn't loading properly, or finally the scripts I copied from rors.org isn't functioning for some reason. Have you checked the javascript console in firebug (or whatever debugger you use)?

Comment: When I used bootstrap 1.3.0 I used jquery-rails gem and in application.js I had //= require jquery and //= require jquery_ujs

Now with bootstrap 2.1.1 they say you have to add <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> to your code, so I deleted jquery-rails gem and //= require jquery and //= require jquery_ujs from application.js because it gives an error.

Comment: Hmm well the first of those two is the basic jquery library, and you're right if you include `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js` then you have to probably remove that. But `//= require jquery_ujs` is the integration of rails with jquery that allows the dynamic links (such as the delete link with confirmation) to work, so you will still have to include that. Can you try including only `jquery_ujs` again?

Comment: I did as you said and it gives me this error:

Sprockets::FileNotFound

couldn't find file 'jquery_ujs' in application.js

Comment: Do you still have the rails jquery integration gem in your Gemfile? i.e. `gem 'jquery-rails'`

Comment: No. I deleted jquery-rails from Gemfile

Comment: Ah well that makes sense, then it won't work ;) You'll have to restore the gem and re-include jquery_ujs or there will be no scripting to handle the dynamic delete button. You can restore the gem without adding the basic jquery script include to application.js.

Comment: Yes!! It works!. Thank you so much. How can I pass more parameters to modal (html text to show, etc.)? I tried to add text: 'Hello' but it shows undefined

Comment: Great, congrats! ;) To add additional data, you can see the confirmation script queries data-confirm (`message = link.attr 'data-confirm'`) on the link to get the message to display in the modal html: `<p>#{message}</p>`. The data-confirm text is added by rails by the `link_to` helper when used with `confirm:`. You can add additional data attributes manually, for example: `link_to 'delete', my_object, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', 'data-my-message' => 'Hello world!'` You can access that in the confirmation script using jquery: `message = link.attr 'data-my-message'`

Comment: Thank you. If I try to pass html code in 'data-my-message' it shows link in bad style. How can I do this?

Comment: Happy to help but you may want to start a different question on this topic. The comment box is too short to give a good explanation on how data attributes work and it's no longer the same question we started with :) Make sure you copy/paste the link as you have it in your html in the new question so we can see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449582/html-text-in-twitter-bootstrap-modal-data-attributes-parameter

Comment: Works well for me. Thanks Peter! Hmm… me thinks with would be a great addition to bootbox_rails.