# html text in twitter bootstrap modal data attributes parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

This comes from [Twitter Bootstrap modal rails delete button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429066/twitter-bootstrap-modal-rails-delete-button-not-working)

How can I pass html code to show in Twitter Bootstrap modal? Here is the link

```
<%= link_to t('delete'), post, method: :delete, confirm: t('delete_this_question'), 'data-my-message' => raw(post.text), class: 'label' %>
```

post.text is HTML code. Now it shows link in bad format.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is probably your use of "raw". If you use raw html inside your link_to helper it will probably mess up the link's quoting. For example you might get something like this:

```
<a href="..." data-my-message="Hello <a href="/foo">world</a>" ...>
```

And that would mess up your link tag. I'm not sure how the rest of your view fits together but I think you should just be able to drop the 'raw' method:

```
<%= link_to t('delete'), post, method: :delete, confirm: t('delete_this_question'), 'data-my-message' => post.text, class: 'label' %>
```

Comment: Peter you are right but modal does not show HTML code exactly like in the view

Comment: Do you mean the HTML does not get rendered properly or the css styles are not applied? The latter makes sense, post.text is rendered in the modal which is a different location in the DOM. That means any applied css may have to be modified to render it properly. If the former, then it might be an escaping issue although that should be handled by Rails automatically.

Comment: Thank you Peter. CSS styles were not applied. I've made some changes and now modal is showing OK but problem is that when I click Cancel button in modal it closes it but background opacity does not change and web is unusable.

I tried to change opacity in css file but problem continues. 

Any idea? Thanks